# What are closure and boundary of $(-\infty,\infty)\times (0,T)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For $T>0$, define
$$
\Omega_T:=(-\infty,\infty)\times (0,T).
$$

I wonder how the closure $\overline{\Omega}_T$ and the boundary $\partial\Omega_T$ look like.

---

For example, if we want to impose boundary conditions I need to know what $\partial\Omega_T$ is... or another scenario: Applying some maximum principle which tells me there cant be a minima in the interior... what is the boundary, what the interior here?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture? $(-\infty,\infty)\times(0,T)$ is an infinite horizontal strip.

Comment: It could make sense to make the ambient set and the topology you use explicit. It is likely it is the two-dimensional real space with the "usual" topology (the one, induced by a norm on the space), but it is not certain either.

Comment: @quid This is used in a book about maximum principles without any comment about topologies etc. So I guess some "usual" topology (as you say) is meant.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, I drew a picture. Nonetheless, its not clear to me how to handle the "sides"  at infinity and minus infinity....

Answer (score 0):

In the usual topology you have
$$
\partial \Omega_T=\partial\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R~:~0<y<T\}=\{(x,y)~:~y=0\text{ or }y=T\}=(\mathbb R\times\{0\})\cup (\mathbb R\times\{T\}).
$$
And $\Omega_T$ is open, so the interior of $\Omega_T$ is $\Omega_T$ itself.

But this is much more basic than the maximum principle...

Answer (score 0):

The set $\Omega_T$ is a subset of $S = (-\infty,\infty)\times [0,T]$, which is a closed set in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. So the closure of $\Omega_T$ is contained in

$\tag 1 S= \mathbb R \times \{0\} \; \bigcup \; \Omega_T \; \bigcup \; \mathbb R \times \{T\}$

Now every open rectangle containing the $(x, 0)$ must intersect $\Omega_T$, and a similar statement can be made for any point $(x, T) \in \mathbb R \times \{T\}$. So the closure of $\Omega_T$ is indeed $S$. Also, it is easy to see that the $\partial\Omega_T$ is given by

$\tag 2 S= \mathbb R \times \{0\} \; \bigcup \; \mathbb R \times \{T\}$